# GRUB rescue error on installed Ubuntu 13.04 with my Windows 8 pro. I tried to merge a partition of e drive that was not my os drive

Tags: dual-boot, 13.04, grubrescue

I have installed Ubuntu 13.04 on my Windows 8 Pro of HP dv6 7012tx. When I am opening my laptop, its showing these error before showing Windows 8 logo.

```
error : unknown filesystem.
grub rescue>
```

Please help me to solve my problem as HP customer care told me to format my entire laptop what I don't wanna do. Help me to resolve or uninstalled Ubuntu via commandline.

Thanks.

Comment: i am able to open ubuntu but not win 8.....there any permanent solution to finish this problem....if there need to remove ubuntu...no problem

Answer (score 1):

Run a live Ubuntu CD or USB, then open Terminal , you need to install boot-repair, it just simple tool to install GRUB boot , and scanning for other OS exiting on your HDD,

1. Connect to Internet.
2. Open Terminal
3. then type `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update`
4. then `sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)`
5. Launch Boot Repair from Terminal : `boot-repair`
6. Press Recommended Repair.

[You can find fore info Here.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is incomplete installation of ubuntu which has caused an error while booting it as the default operating system. If you are using a bootable pen drive or a disc, next time boot from one of these devices from the BIOS and complete your installation.

Comment: thanks for reply... but i had installed ubuntu on my lappy along with win 8 from boot menu successfully.... i had used it too but this problem arised when i merged two drives(drive e and drive i) into a single drive e.....

Answer (score 0):

disable secure boot then try you will see grub menu
if its still not work then run via live CD/pendrive and install boot repair and run that in recommended setting

you may see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: i can see the ubuntu recovery menu....via some code like

Comment: set root=(hd0,6)

Comment: set prefix=(hd0,6)/boot/grub     there is a update grub bootloader,repair broken packages etc option...it will help???

Comment: thanks yr... my problem is solved by using installing and using boot repair in ubuntu 13.04...... thanks all

Comment: its done by doing these things....set root=(hd0,6)
set prefix=(hd0,6)/boot/grub
insmod normal
normal

after then select ubuntu and open it via boot option....
then press CTRL+ALT+T for open terminal
install boot repair(for more help about how to install and use command of boot repair go to ubuntu community help of boot repair)
after installing open the boot repair(in my case it open automatically)
and do the recommanded repair.....after that reboot your system....thats all...